# what is view and how to view in laravel 8 project

Tags: laravel

How to add data in array global in appServiceProvider of Laravel which could be used globally for select option field in blade.php

Comment: Why not in a config file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use view()->share in boot function of AppServiceProvider.php Class under Providers to make data accessible globally like

```
   public function boot()

{


 $departments =[

            'IT'=> 'Information Technology Department',

            'BIL'=> 'Billing Department',

            'ACC'=> 'Accounts Department',
            
        ];

    view()->share('departments',$departments);
    

}
```

and you can use this data stored in $departmentrespectivly in blade.php

```
<select>
     <option value="">Choose One</option>
     @foreach($departments as $key=> $value)
     <option value="{{ $key }}">{{ $value }}</option>
     @endforeach
   </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `View::share` to share data within all `views`. Here is an example from the [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#sharing-data-with-all-views)

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        View::share('key', 'value');
    }
}
```